# R assignment to list element using single vs double brackets

Tags: r, list

R has two indexing operators, `[]` and `[[]]`. When inputting a single index, the single-bracket will return that element within a list, whereas a double-bracket will return the element itself, not inside a list. During list element assignment, I understand that using the double-brackets is the way to go (and the more logical between the two options). However, only one of the lines in the code block below is unsuccessful.

```r
my_list = vector("list", 1)

my_list[1] = 25
my_list[[1]] = 89
my_list[1] = 20:25
my_list[[1]] = 85:89
```

`my_list[1] = 20:25` is unsuccessful, and gives the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In my_list[1] = 20:25 :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Although I don't understand what the warning is saying in this context, it makes sense that the line does not complete assignment. My question is this: why does `my_list[1] = 25` work for assignment? Shouldn't it also fail?

Comment: Note that `my_list[1:6] = 20:25` will work. It seems that if you want to assign an atomic vector with `[` R will run `as.list()` or similar on the input. Probably what you are after can be achieved with `my_list[1:6] = list(20:25)`

Comment: My understanding is that `my_list[1] = 20:25` takes `20:25`, changes it into a list of six items and tries to assign these items one by one into the items of `my_list` defined by the subscript `[1]`. However, since the subscript only defines the first item, only the first assignment (`20`) is performed and the rest of the assigned list items (`21:25`) is thrown away and R will warn you that the numbers of items on the left and right hand side of the assignment did not match.

Comment: using `mylist[1]` is calling the first element of the list. you cannot assign anything of more than length 1 to this list. ie the list is of length 1 so must assign anything of length 1. eg another list of length 1 etc. Notice that `mylist[1][1]` is the same as `mylist[1]`. Infact you could repeat that  `[1]` several times and it will be the same thing ie `mylist[1][1][1][1][1]` will still be exactly same as `mylist[1]`. On the other hand `mylist[[1]]` calls onto the elements of the first list rather than the first list itself. Hence can take many elements

Comment: RTFM, or better yet,  RTRI (the R-Inferno)  for details of all sorts of oddities like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning message tells you that '**The assignment cannot be completed because the length of values do not match element length**'. If you use a single bracket [] you can only assign a single value. But when you try to assign a sequence of [20:25] to my_list[1] you are replacing values of length 6 in element of length 1 which is unsuccessful. If you want to assign a sequence using a single bracket you could put the values into a list():

```
my_list[1] = list(20:25)

 my_list
[[1]]
[1] 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

Hope it could helps.